# Tensor Algebra help

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on my homework for a class, and I am really stuck

the question I was given was:

prove that S(a ⊗ b) = (Sa) ⊗ b

Does anyone have any tips on how to solve this?

For further explanation this is problem 6a from this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=W-0b09yIgq4C&lpg=PP1&dq=an%20introduction%20to%20continuum%20mechanics&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false) on the page the link goes to

Comment: Maybe you could say what $S$ is supposed to be.

Comment: sorry I should have elaborated further. S is suppose to be a tensor map while a and b are supposed to be vectors.

Comment: What do you mean by "tensor map"?  Is it linear?  What is its domain and range?

Comment: upon further looking at the book, it looks like a linear map. But I guess what they were just trying to get across is that it is a Tensor. such that v = Su. The hint in the back of the book says apply each side of the identity to an arbitrary vector v.

Comment: The terminology of the book does not seem to be standard. In order to get help, you really need to elaborate more on what S, a, and b precisely are. And v and u.

Answer (score 1):

The important identity that is missing from the Google Books preview is $(a \otimes b) v = (b \cdot v)a$.
Using this, and looking at the image of a vector $v$ under $S(a \otimes b)$ you get
$$\begin{aligned}
S(a \otimes b) v &= S((b \cdot v)a)\\
&= (b \cdot v) (Sa)\\
&= ((Sa) \otimes b) v
\end{aligned}$$
Hence $S(a \otimes b) = (Sa) \otimes b$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an easy problem using the universal property of tensor products provided that I can understand the question, it seems that the precise definition in the linked book is blocked and it is truly weird o find S operating on both tensors , $a$ tensor product $b$ and vectors, $a$.
As far as I am concerned, it is either a typing problem or an unexplained notation arising error.